# I am having trouble with a boolean Acceptor

Tags: c++, boolean

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void WorldBuilder();
bool Acceptor();

int main()
{
bool IsAcceptable = (false);

while (IsAcceptable == (false))
    {
        WorldBuilder(); // build world
            IsAcceptable = Acceptor();
    }
    return 0;
}

// Builds the world
void WorldBuilder()
{
std::cout << "Building World...\n";
return;
}

bool Acceptor()
    {
        std::cout << "Is world build acceptable? (y/n) ";
        std::string qIsAcceptable = "";
        std::cin >> qIsAcceptable;

if (qIsAcceptable[1] == 'y')
    {
        return (true);
    }
else if (qIsAcceptable[1] == 'n')
    {
        return (false);
    }

}
```

When I debug it goes from the elses without changing the IsAcceptable boolean and goes back to WorldBuilder() and boolean trips to true whatever the input.

I feel like there must be something I don't understand about booleans.

Comment: I suggest using a debugger or cout statements to see the values of variables in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
if (qIsAcceptable[1] == 'y')
    {
        return (true);
    }
else if (qIsAcceptable[1] == 'n')
    {
        return (false);
    }
```

to

```
if (qIsAcceptable[0] == 'y')
    {
        return (true);
    }
else if (qIsAcceptable[0] == 'n')
    {
        return (false);
    }
```

C/C++ array arithmetics starts from `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Nice. I knew there was something really basic I was missing, but I wasn't sure what it was. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BrendanSleanbeck No problem!

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
bool Acceptor()
{
    std::cout << "Is world build acceptable? (y/n) ";
    std::string qIsAcceptable = "";
    std::cin >> qIsAcceptable;

    if (qIsAcceptable[1] == 'y')
    {
        return (true);
    }
    else if (qIsAcceptable[1] == 'n')
    {
        return (false);
    }

}
```

You are checking the characters the wrong way. Array sub scripting begins at zero, not one. Your code should now be:

```
#include <cctype>
//....
bool Acceptor()
{
    std::cout << "Is world build acceptable? (y/n) ";
    char qIsAcceptable = 'b';
    std::cin >> qIsAcceptable;

    if (std::tolower(qIsAcceptable) == 'y')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (std::tolower(qIsAcceptable) == 'n')
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Also, if you've noticed, I have removed the parentheses around `(true)` and `(false)`. They are not needed, so you should remove them. I have also added changes to my code, that you can see if you want. One is converting the user-input to a char, and next is checking for all possibilities, using `std::tolower`. See above.

Comment: If there is any errata here, please feel free to point it out!